# Override/Disable @Startup class

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb, startup, java-ee-8

I am talking of a Java EE application and a Wildfly application server.
Assume I have a jar as a library that defines the following class:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
class StartupService {

    @PostConstruct
    public void onConstruct() {
        /* do something */
    }
}
```

Now, I have my actual war project (maven project) that has the jar, described above, as a dependency. So the class `StartupService` is executed when the war is deployed to Wildfly and started.

Is there a way to override the behavior or disable `StartupService` in my actual project?

Answer (score 1):

Try with defining the following ejb-jar.xml:

```
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="3.1"

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">

    <enterprise-beans>

        <session>

           <ejb-name>StartupService</ejb-name>

           <init-on-startup>false</init-on-startup>

        </session>

    </enterprise-beans>

</ejb-jar>
```

It must be located in the WAR module's WEB-INF directory. I haven't checked it myself but it should work.

Comment: When your EJBs are deployed using JARs, the (in this case overriding) deployment descriptor must be located in the JARs META-INF directory.